# Sus Chords - Whole Step Or Half?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony

Is the fourth in a sus4 chord always a whole step away from the third? Or is it based on what diatonic note is next in the scale?

Example:

In the key of C major:

`Dm sus4` = `D` `G` `A`

It is a whole step resolution from `G` to `F`

But, what about a chord that has a half step diatonic fourth near the third?

`C sus4` = `C` `F` `G`

It is only a half step resolution from `F` to `E`

Which begs the question, what would a `sus4` chord mean if you were playing the whole tone scale, or perhaps the blues scale?

(After looking at this, I don't understand what the difference is from a `F 6/4` and a `Csus4`).

Comment: Csus4 is C F G. Which is the difference between that and F 6/4 because that's still C F A.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I seem to always spell things wrong. :( edited

Answer (score 6):

Despite the votes on this question (and answers so far), I don't believe anyone has actually answered the question:

> Which begs the question, what would a sus4 chord mean if you were playing the whole tone scale, or perhaps the blues scale?

First, we have to understand what a suspension is:

Suspensions have **three parts**:

- Preparation - introduces a non-chord tone
- Suspension - sustains that non-chord tone (often through a harmonic change)
- Resolution - resolves the non-chord tone to a chord tone (almost always downward by step)

[image]

In the example, we begin with an Em6/4 (second-inversion), but on beat 4 the E moves to F, a note that does not fit in an E minor triad. The new note is sustained through a harmonic change (it still does not fit into this new chord), and then finally resolves downward by step to a chord tone. In this case, it happens to be a C major triad.

So, back to the question, *What would a sus4 chord mean if you were playing the whole tone scale, or perhaps the blues scale?*

Well, using suspension predicate the idea of tension and release. You create tension by moving from a chord tone to a non-chord tone, changing the chord, and then bringing it back.

Blues is a predominately tonal musical genre, and like most genres, is not rigid. *Midnight Waltz* by Cedar Walton, is a 24-bar blues in 3/4 that makes extensive use of suspensions. In this context, suspensions (4-3 suspension) is used as an Upper Neighbor Tone that prolongs the larger harmonic regions forward, creating a sense of movement:

In music that uses whole-tone elements, you would need to handle it differently. The whole tone scale is by its own invention and purpose, non-functional, harmonically speaking. Suspensions, as we have established, serve a harmonic function. So, in order to use a harmonic-functioning device in a predominately non-functional context, you would have to manufacture the impression of harmonic function. Otherwise, the effect is meaningless. The answer to *that* question, is for another time.

So, to summarize, as another stack user said quite succinctly:

> "An argument can be made that any sus chord that satisfies these theoretical elements is valid. In the blues context, both a half step above the third and a whole step above the third could theoretically achieve this. Midnight Waltz provides an example where a whole step is used. Other examples probably exist where a half step is used." - jdjazz

Comment: I think this is an outstanding answer that could be improved with one small addition to summarily answer the Q. Maybe something like: "An argument can be made that any sus chord that satisfies these theoretical elements is valid. In the blues context, both a half step above the third and a whole step above the third could theoretically achieve this. Midnight Waltz provides an example where a whole step is used. Other examples probably exist where a half step is used." I'm sure Brad Mehldau has resolved a major third to a minor third in a blues context, but I'll have to dig to find an example.

Comment: Regarding whole tone, I think what you're saying is that the whole tone chord isn't supposed to sound resolved in the first place, & the chord tones themselves are designed to produce the tension one would hope to achieve from a sus chord. I think an argument can be made that if a song establishes a whole tone chord in the listener's ear, then you can now create a sus sound for that whole tone chord. For ex: resolving `G Db♭ E♭` to `G B E♭` or even `G Db♭ F` to `G B E♭`. I don't hear the same effect from `G C E♭` to `G B E♭` because this sounds like a i-V (e.g., Cmin – G7alt).

Comment: @jdjazz Wonderful, thanks for the comment! (If you like, then please upvote!) :)

I'm going to leave your comment / my answer as-is so that people can see your comment. If I were to edit my answer, I would just copy/paste your words as they are succinct and descriptive.

Comment: If you think my comment as is would be a nice addition, I say go for it and edit it into your answer. On other stackexchange sites, I know comments are periodically deleted/meant to be temporary. Your answer gave me a way to think about how one might successfully produce a whole tone sus sound, which is really cool. Thanks! (On a separate note, this is a great example of why music theory has value!)

Comment: @jdjazz With whole-tone scales, the point is to emphasize all notes equally. This thinking is inherently non-functional, harmonically speaking. Functional harmony establishes a hierarchy of pitch-importance. Music incorporating whole-tone scales achieves tension and resolution through other means, like texture, density, orchestration, and rhythm, for example.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the clarification. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

For starters, C F A cannot be a sus: it's F major in second inversion! Whole tone and blues scales don't use the same 'rules' as diatonics - they can't, due to their make-up.

Sus chords, be they 2 or 4, are in one way like 'power chords'. They have lost the defining third, making them neither major nor minor. The fact that the sus 4 note is a semitone away from that 3rd in major but a tone from it in minor is beside the point. It *is* the 4th note, hence sus 4, in a way replacing that third, which will usually be returned sooner rather than later. So, writing a sus as Dsus4 or Dm sus4 becomes somewhat academic.

Answer (score 0):

The 'sus' note is a semitone above the major 3rd, a tone above the minor 3rd.  Which one will you resolve it to?  Or will you just leave it there?  Your choice!

F 6/4 is a second inversion F chord.  C, F, A.   Csus is C, F, G.

Comment: Csus*4* is C F G. Csus*2* is C D G. Csus doesn't really exist as such. And - C F G can also be Fsus 2, and C D G can also be Gsus4.

Comment: I've seen plenty of music where "sus" with no numeral is assumed by the publisher/engraver to be understood as sus4.